# order by ..PIVOT SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a pivot like this

```
  Select 
    CalendarYear,CalendarMonth,
    count([ID])  as NumberOfOrders 
  FROM[Database].[dbo].[DataTable]
  PIVOT
  (
   SUM(NumberOfOrders) FOR CalendarMonth IN
                       ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
  )ASpv1
```

I wish to order by the CalendarYear, CalendarMonth, but cannot do this because I cannot place an order by before the pivot. How can I do this please

please help

Comment: Hi tried just ... order by  CalendarMonth ...cannot do this says invalid column, please help

Answer (score 1):

**Notice the sub-query**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] int,[CalendarYear] int,[CalendarMonth] int)  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,2019,1)
,(2,2019,1)
,(3,2019,2)


Select *
 From  (
        Select CalendarYear
              ,CalendarMonth
              ,NumberOfOrders = count(ID)
         From  @YourTable
         Group By CalendarYear,CalendarMonth
       ) src
 Pivot ( sum(NumberOfOrders) for CalendarMonth in ( [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12]) )  pvt
 Order By CalendarYear
```

**Returns**

[image]